# Scala: what is the best way to append an element to an Array?

Tags: arrays, scala, append

Say I have an `Array[Int]` like

```
val array = Array( 1, 2, 3 )
```

Now I would like to append an element to the array, say the value `4`, as in the following example:

```
val array2 = array + 4     // will not compile
```

I can of course use `System.arraycopy()` and do this on my own, but there must be a Scala library function for this, which I simply could not find. Thanks for any pointers!

Notes:

1. I am aware that I can append another Array of elements, like in the following line, but that seems too round-about:

   ```
   val array2b = array ++ Array( 4 )     // this works
   ```
2. I am aware of the advantages and drawbacks of List vs Array and here I am for various reasons specifically interested in extending an Array.

#### Edit 1

Thanks for the answers pointing to the `:+` operator method. This is what I was looking for. Unfortunately, it is rather slower than a custom append() method implementation using `arraycopy` -- about two to three times slower. Looking at the implementation in `SeqLike[]`, a builder is created, then the array is added to it, then the append is done via the builder, then the builder is rendered. Not a good implementation for arrays. I did a quick benchmark comparing the two methods, looking at the fastest time out of ten cycles. Doing 10 million repetitions of a single-item append to an 8-element array instance of some class `Foo` takes 3.1 sec with `:+` and 1.7 sec with a simple `append()` method that uses `System.arraycopy();` doing 10 million single-item append repetitions on 8-element arrays of Long takes 2.1 sec with `:+` and 0.78 sec with the simple `append()` method. Wonder if this couldn't be fixed in the library with a custom implementation for `Array`?

#### Edit 2

For what it's worth, I filed a ticket:
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5017

Comment: Why not use [`ArrayBuffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html) and its `+=` method? That will give you amortized O(1) append.

Comment: In scala, `System.arraycopy(...)` is replaced by `Array.copy(...)`

Comment: You are aware of the advantages and drawbacks of List vs Array, but are surprised of benchmark results of 10 million appends?

Comment: Can you run again your benchmark using an `ArrayBuffer` which is converted after the *last* append to an array (with `toArray`) ?

Comment: @paradigmatic: The benchmark of course was not 10 million appends to the same array but 10 million repetitions of a single-item append to an 8-element array. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Seems fixed in https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/1739?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You can use `:+` to append element to array and `+:` to prepend it:

```
0 +: array :+ 4
```

should produce:

```
res3: Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

It's the same as with any other implementation of `Seq`.

Comment: It is the same for any other scala *ordered* collection, it does not work with set for example (as prepend and append doesn't mean anything for a Set).

Comment: @Nicolas Any sequence. _Ordered_ implies _sorted_.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I've just have a small memory hole when I wrote the comment and I didn't find the obvious word "sequence"

Comment: @tenshi would all these operators create a new array? Yes, it does (from :+ code) `Array.copy(repr, 0, result, 0, repr.length)`

Answer (score 66):

```
val array2 = array :+ 4
//Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Works also "reversed":

```
val array2 = 4 +: array
Array(4, 1, 2, 3)
```

There is also an "in-place" version:

```
var array = Array( 1, 2, 3 )
array +:= 4
//Array(4, 1, 2, 3)
array :+= 0
//Array(4, 1, 2, 3, 0)
```

Comment: I just wonder why Array collection do not use the append() method , just as the ArrayBuffer. In my opinion,it is more Coordination and unify than use a new operator :+/+:

Answer (score 8):

The easiest might be:

```
Array(1, 2, 3) :+ 4
```

Actually, Array can be implcitly transformed in a [`WrappedArray`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray)

Comment: In that case, that would be the higher priority conversion to ArrayOps